# What's wrong with this code with permtest function in R?

Tags: r, statistics, permutation, analysis

```
    ID pounds Drug
1   1   46.4    B
2   2   40.4    A
3   3   27.6    B
4   4   93.2    B
5   5   28.8    A
6   6   36.0    A
7   7   81.2    B
8   8   14.4    B
9   9  64.0    A
10 10   29.6    A
```

My code is

```
test <-permtest(data1$pounds[Drug=='A'],data1$pounds[Drug=='B'])
```

But I get an error saying object 'Drug' not found.
Help!

Comment: replace `Drug` with `data1$Drug` in both places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to extract the column with `$` or `[[`.  Here it is searching for an object 'Drug' in the global env, which is not created there, but only within the environment of the 'data1'.  So, either use `$/[[`

```
permtest(data1$pounds[data1$Drug=='A'],data1$pounds[data1$Drug=='B'])
```

Or use `with`

```
with(data1, permtest(pounds[Drug == 'A'], pounds[Drug == 'B']))
```

Comment: This is what I got after editing: Error in 1:nrow(mat) : argument of length 0

Comment: @TongClaireXu is this from `library(permtest)` i see that package is archived.  Also, do you have a `data.frame` or `matrix`

Comment: data1 is a data.frame. Thanks!

Comment: @TongClaireXu I cant find the permtest as it in archived

Comment: I installed the package BHH2 by downloading the file someone sent me. Permtest is from there.

Comment: I got it. The code is the same, but I did it just then, and it worked. thanks!